# How can I extract specific terms from each string line?

Tags: java, text

I have a serious problem with extracting terms from each string line. To be more specific, I have one csv formatted file which is actually not csv format (it saves all terms into line[0] only)

So, here's just example string line among thousands of string lines;

---

test.csv

line1 : "31451 　　  CID005319044 　　15939353　　    C8H14O3S2   　　　**beta-lipoic acid**　　   C1CS@S[C@@H]1CCCCC(=O)O "

line2 : "12232 COD05374044 23439353　　C924O3S2 　　　**saponin**　　 CCCC(=O)O "

line3 : "9048 　 CTD042032　23241　　C3HO4O3S2　**Berberine**　 [C@@H]1CCCCC(=O)O "

---

I want to extract **"beta-lipoic acid"** ,**"saponin"** and **"Berberine"** only which is located in 5th position.
You can see there are big spaces between terms, so that's why I said 5th position.

In this case, how can I extract terms located in 5th position for each line?

one more thing ;

the length of whitespace between each six terms is not always equal.
the length could be one,two,three or four..five... something like that..

Comment: if the length of white could be one, two, three or four five etc, what  will happen on beta-lipoic acid. There is a space there. any other way to determine the space within the word or it is the delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another try:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
    // The amount of columns per row, where each column is seperated by an arbitrary number
    //  of spaces or tabs
    final static int COLS = 7;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Tokens:");
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt")).useDelimiter("\\s+")) {
            // Counten the current column-id
            int n = 0;
            String tmp = "";
            StringBuilder item = new StringBuilder();
            // Operating of a stream
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                tmp = scanner.next();
                n += 1;
                // If we have reached the fifth column, take its content and append the
                // sixth column too, as the name we want consists of space-separated
                // expressions. Feel free to customize of your name-layout varies.
                if (n % COLS == 5) {
                    item.setLength(0);
                    item.append(tmp);
                    item.append(" ");
                    item.append(scanner.next());
                    n += 1;

                    System.out.println(item.toString()); // Doing  some stuff with that
                                                         //expression we got
                }
            }
        }
        catch(java.io.IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your line[]'s type is String

```
String s = line[0];
String[] split = s.split("   ");
return split[4]; //which is the fifth item
```

For the delimiter, if you want to go more precisely, you can use regular expression.

Comment: Why not `s.split("\\s+")`?

Comment: @Alexander_Winter: this would split up the `beta-lipoic` from the `acid` which has to be one element. But indeed, just three spaces won't work, since the String is splitted by some spaces and tabs...

Comment: @Alexander_Winter: `s+` is **at least** one space. So it's in the range [1-n]. So one space is accepted and it won't work!

Comment: Then take \s\s+, it should contain everything from 2 spaces to unlimited.

Comment: @Alexander_Winter "\\s+" should be good, cuz there is a space between beta-lipoic acid, I am waiting for the user to clarify more.

Comment: Thank you all of you. i tried your suggestion. but there's some false postive exsits. I mean the length of whitespace between each term is not equal..

Answer (score 0):

How is the column separated? For example, if the columns are separated by tab character, I believe you can use the `split` method. Try using the below:

```
String[] parts = str.split("\\t");
```

Your expected result will be in `parts[4]`.

Comment: Thank you, rcs. but the problem is when it faces with length 1 whitespace like 31451 CID005319044....

Answer (score 0):

Just use `String.split()` using a regex for at least 2 whitespace characters:

```
String foo = "31451 　　 CID005319044 　　15939353　　 C8H14O3S2 　　　beta-lipoic acid　　 C1CS@S[C@@H]1CCCCC(=O)O";
String[] bar = foo.split("\\s\\s");
bar[4]; // beta-lipoic acid
```

Comment: `foo[4]` should be `bar[4]`. But apart from that, this wouldn't work either, because if you're splitting by two whitespaces and you have four whitespaces in a row, it would result in one element more. So your index `4` is also incorrect. I mean... the requirement is not detailed enough.

Comment: Thank you desertlvy, yes you are right. the length of whitespaces between terms could be one or two or three ..... i mean i can not correctly split string line using split()...